# use one database connection in all classes

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm

I'm new to WPF (and application development in general), and I want to connect to my database and use that connection to query it in all my Model classes. I've written the connection string in the mainwindow code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Connect();
    }
  ...etc
```

And the DBConnection class looks like this

```
 class DBConnection
{
    private OracleConnection connection;
    private OracleCommand command;
    private bool autoDisconnect;


    public void Connect(bool autoDisconnect = true)
    {

        this.autoDisconnect = autoDisconnect;
        try
        {
            if (connection == null)
            {
                connection = new OracleConnection("CONNECTION DETAILS");
            }
            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        { }
    }
..... etc
```

but I want to create the connection and the `db` object somewhere so that in all my models can just call the classes of `DBConnection` without having to create a new object every time

for example, here's a model

```
public class Authentication
{
    string username;
    string password;

    public static bool Authenticate(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        db.SetSQL("SQL STATEMENT HERE");
        db.ExecuteTransactions();
    }
...etc
```

where `SetSQL` and `ExecuteTransactions` are methods of the DBConnection Class

So where and how can I (simply) connect to the database so it'll be constant throughout the whole application? Its just one window with varying UserControls so I thought it'd be ok to connect in the mainwindow code behind

Comment: Not a good idea. Connections are a valuable resource that should not be kept for the lifetime of an application. This could be potentially a great bootleneck on your server side. They should be created, used, disposed as soon as possible. Search about Connection Pooling for Oracle and your provider (Microsoft, Oracle or....)

Comment: If you want to stick to your idea after @Steve's comment. I would suggest you to read about two things : singletons (go easy on them they have specific use cases), and more importantly the `static` keyword.

Comment: @Steve, I didn't know that! So should I open the connection when it needs to be used (like validating a login) and close it afterwards (logged in), and then open/close again for every separate CRUD action?

Comment: Usually, yes... Consider also that in NET we have the Using statement that is specifically used for this kind of objects (the ones that implements the IDisposable interface like the connection)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But holding a connection is not good
And sharing a connection across multiple queries is not good
What if you want to do some parallel stuff in the future
Connection pooling is very efficient is the recommended way
I know it seems like a lot

```
static private dbConnectionString = "CONNECTION DETAILS";  

using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(dbConnectionString))
{
   try 
   {   
      connection.Open();
      using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
      {
          ......
          using(OracleDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
          }
      }
   }
   catch(OracleException ex)
   {
   }
   finally 
   {
      connection.Close();   
   }
}
```

or you can wrap that in a class DBConnection

```
using (DB Connection dbConnection = new DBConnection())
{
}
```

and you would typically not use an ExecuteTrasaction for just a single sql statement

this is **not** a good idea

```
db.SetSQL("SQL STATEMENT HERE");
```

should be using parmeterized queries
I know you want to make it simple but it is not
You may want to look at like an entity framework

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a good tutorial that covers connection pooling in wpf? I don't understand if the first codeblock is a class on its own, or goes in each model, or where the queries go

Comment: @North What is there to understand about pooling?  Create, open, use, and close.   You use the first code block in model or you can wrap it in a DBConnection as I stated.  And as I stated you should be using parmeterized queries so a generic dbConnection is limited.   If you don't know where the queries go then I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think the best is to create a new class or put it into your DBConnection class. And in that class declare your connection as static public.
2. Also I'd use property.
   something like this

   ```
   static private DBConnection _db=null;

   static public DBConnection Db
   {
       get
       {
           if (_db==null) Db=new DBConnection(); //You can also add connection or any initialisation
           return _db;
       }
       set { _db = value; }
   }
   ```

PS In WPF usually don't put code into code behind. All code in WPF are inn Models or ViewModels